# What is the "nutritional calorie" count of beer?

Tags: nutrition

Beer has a fairly high calorie count - roughly between 150 and 300kcal per serving of 0.5l depending on kind. A significant percent of that is alcohol though, which is fully metabolized without any reserves whatsoever being retained - empty calories without actual nutritional contribution to organism.

I wonder what is the actual typical contribution of beer to human body energy reserves - energy from sugars, fats, proteins? How should I count beer in my diet?

Comment: There's such a *massive* variance across styles that I'm not sure this is answerable. Though perhaps a better question would be if there's a formula to subtract out the alcohol based on ABV?

Comment: related [how is light beer produced](http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/250/how-is-light-beer-produced/252#252)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Despite the variance I guess the answer of "between X-Y% of the original" would be a viable answer, or a relation of alcohol content. A few words how *actually* alcohol contributes (e.g. alcohol burned readily might, or might not create savings allowing to store other ingredients that would be otherwise burned).

Answer (score 5):

It really comes down to the specific beer you are drinking.

In addition to trace elements, and vitamins, the main dietary contribution of beer is from carbohydrates, proteins and alcohol.

Protein and Carbohydrates provide 4 kcal/g energy, while alcohol provides 7 kcal/g.

With dietary planing, you need to look at the specific foods you plan to consume, and no different with beer and diet - here you'll need to look at specific beers to determine nutritional and energy value.